# Recursively Generate Combination Of Every Item in the list

Tags: c#

I have a List

```
List<string> collection = {"a","b"}
```

**I want to give a numerical value i.e. Weight e.g. 2**

What I want is:

For the given weight, get all possible combinations:

```
a0b0, a1b0, a2b0
a0b1, a1b1, a2b1
a0b2, a2b2
```

where 0,1,2 are the values from 0 to the given weight value

I am struggle to generate it.  Please guide?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

Comment: Try E.Lippert's CartesianProduct with `var x = CartesianProduct(new List<List<string>>() { 
                new List<string> { "a" }, 
                new List<string> {"0","1","2"},
                new List<string> { "b" },
                new List<string> {"0","1","2"},
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Using Recursion:***

```
static void ShowCombination(List<string> mlist, int value,int current=0,string stringleft="")
    {
            if (current == mlist.Count-1) // if this is the last item in the list
            {
                for (int m = 0; m <= value; m++) //loop through the value add it to the existing string-stringleft
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(stringleft  + mlist[current]+m.ToString()); 
                }
            }
            else // if there are more than 1 item left in the list
            {
                string currentstring = mlist[current]; //get current string in the list eg. "a" 
                stringleft = stringleft + currentstring ; //reset existing string -- eg "a"
                for (int m = 0; m <= value; m++)  //loop through the value add it to the existing 'stringleft' pass it and the new current index for recursion
                {
                    string stopass = stringleft +  m.ToString(); // eg. "a0"; "a1" 
                    ShowCombination(mlist, value, current + 1, stopass); 
                }
            }
    }
```

[image]

*Usage:*

```
ShowCombination(new List<string>() {"a", "b"}, 2);
```

*Output:*

```
a0b0
a0b1
a0b2
a1b0
a1b1
a1b2
a2b0
a2b1
a2b2
```

Comment: This works perfect.  I have some questions.  I understand it is going through first a from 0 to value and then b from 0 to value but how is it doing it? Can you please help me understand?  When you take the current item from the collection and calls the function again recursively, does it remember what was the current item?  I am not really sure on the second loop you have and what it is doing. Many thanks

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, the current item is passed to the recursion function, please see my added comments in the code.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look more into it.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, Added an image for better explanation.

Comment: Many thanks.  Tell me please, what will be the difference between current + 1 that you are passing in the method VS if before I call the recursive function, I do this: current++.  I noticed that current++ gives totally different results than passing current + 1 in the method

Comment: `current++` will first pass `current` to the function then operate `current=current+1`, check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you truly need **all** possible combinations, use this:

```
List<string> collection = new List<string> {"a","b"};
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
var result = 
from a in collection
from b in collection
from n1 in numbers
from n2 in numbers
select a + n1 + b + n2;
```

This results in 36 items:
a0a0, a0a1, a0a2, a1a0, 
a1a1, 
a1a2, 
a2a0, 
a2a1, 
a2a2, 
a0b0, 
a0b1, 
a0b2, 
a1b0, 
a1b1, 
a1b2, 
a2b0, 
a2b1, 
a2b2, 
b0a0, 
b0a1, 
b0a2, 
b1a0, 
b1a1, 
b1a2, 
b2a0, 
b2a1, 
b2a2, b0b0, b0b1, b0b2, b1b0, b1b1, b1b2, b2b0, b2b1, b2b2

If you only need the combinations you stated in your question, use this:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2 };
var result = 
from n1 in numbers
from n2 in numbers
select "a" + n1 + "b" + n2;
```

This results in only 9 items: 
a0b0,
a0b1,
a0b2,
a1b0,
a1b1,
a1b2,
a2b0,
a2b1,
a2b2

Comment: select "a" + n1 + "b" + n2; a and b are inputs so they can change too

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: I know. I thought you could transfer this to your problem yourself... I don't know if you always have exactly two items in `collection` or not, that's why I refrained from offering a solution that somehow gets `"a"` and `"b"` from `collection`.

Answer (score 0):

This adds not much to @Daniel's answer, just the way you make your *weight* dynamic:

```
int weight = 2;
List<string> collection1 = new List<string>{ "a", "b" };
var collection2 = Enumerable.Range(0, weight + 1);
var combinations=from str1 in collection1 
                 from int1 in collection2 
                 from str2 in collection1 
                 from int2 in collection2 
                 select str1 + int1 + str2 + int2;

foreach (var combi in combinations)
    Console.WriteLine(combi);
```

**Edit**: If you want all permutations, have a look at this project to see how it's implemented. It's working great.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G

For example:

```
List<string> collection1 = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var collection2 = Enumerable.Range(0, weight + 1);
collection1 = collection1.Concat(collection2.Select(i => i.ToString())).ToList();

var permutations = new Facet.Combinatorics.Permutations<String>(collection1);
foreach (IList<String> p in permutations)
{
    String combi = String.Join("", p);
}
```

Comment: what is there are 4 items in colleciton 1?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: Then you get more combinations like `b2c1","b2c2","b2d0","b2d1","b2d2"`.

Comment: but what i want then is a0b0c0d0, a1b0c0d0, a2b0c0d0 and so on

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: Have a look at the `Permutations` class of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G) combinatoric project. I've given a small sample using it above. Generates all possible combinations like `012abcd` and much more.